# JavaScript hard code to loop problem. Setting grandchildren to children to parent

Tags: javascript, loops, parent, children

What I thought was going to be simple enough is turning out to be a headache for days. I can get it to work hard-coding it but cannot get it to work in a loop. This is what i have hard-coded.

```
         let vt = [{animal:"dog"},{color:"green"},{tail:"curly"}];

         vt[0]["children"]={pupname:"harry",pupcolor:"red"}
         vt[0]["children"]["children"]={pupname:"joe",pupcolor:"brown"}
         vt[0]["children"]["children"]["children"]={pupname:"itchy",pupcolor:"black"}

console.log(JSON.stringify(vt));
```

This will give me what i want.

```
[{
    "animal": "dog",
    "children": {
        "pupname": "harry",
        "pupcolor": "red",
        "children": {
            "pupname": "joe",
            "pupcolor": "brown",
            "children": {
                "pupname": "itchy",
                "pupcolor": "black"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "color": "green"
}, {
    "tail": "curly"
}]
```

This is a simplified version and there could be many objects in the array. I cant get it to work in a loop. The ever increasing number of children keys is my problem, or maybe i'm way off track anyway. Any pointers welcome

Comment: What would be the data you're looking to loop over to get this result? Or is the design of that datastructure part of what's got you stuck?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding the exact nature of your problem.  Perhaps it is just me.  However, some things that might be helpful would be including example input and example outputs, explaining the criteria for how the output should be generated, and showing what you have tried thus far.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that:

```js
const vt = [ { animal: 'dog' }, { color: 'green' }, { tail: 'curly' } ];

[ { pupname:'harry', pupcolor:'red'   }
, { pupname:'joe',   pupcolor:'brown' }
, { pupname:'itchy', pupcolor:'black' }
].reduce((a,c)=>a.children = c, vt[0]);

console.log( vt );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```

Comment: Thanks Mister Jojo. That is exactly what i was looking for. Brilliant!!